# Can I download QGIS on a Chromebook?

Tags: qgis

I'm taking a Geographic Informations Course, and I was wondering if I can download this program onto my Chromebook. If so, what would option of "download for" would I click?

Comment: Found instructions here but don't have a Chromebook to test them: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Now-easy-way-of-install-QGIS-on-chromebooks-td5416255.html

Comment: Review this: [Running QGIS on a Chromebook](http://www.statsmapsnpix.com/2016/01/running-qgis-on-chromebook.html)

Answer (score 1):

O'Reilly Has a book called "Mastering Geospatial Development with QGIS 3.x".

This quote is from it:
*"While it is possible to install QGIS on a Chromebook, we would suggest that doing so is for hobbyists looking to explore/test the capabilities of this union and that it would not be suitable for production environments."*

As mentioned in the comments, there are ways to make it done, some of them even mentioned in that book.

Good Luck!

Comment: If you cite a book, it would be great to provide the full metadata and publisher's link: Mastering Geospatial Development with QGIS 3.x - Third Edition by Shammunul Islam, Simon Miles, GISP Menke, GISP Smith Jr., Luigi Pirelli, GISP Van Hoesen. Packt Publishing 2019, ISBN: 9781788999892
https://www.packtpub.com/product/mastering-geospatial-development-with-qgis-3-x-third-edition/9781788999892

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have an Acer 515 and QGIS seems to work well and fast.  I couldn´t understand the (totally obtuse) instructions on the QGIS download site... but this seemed to load the Long Term Release OK for me... And by the way I don´t agree that Chromebooks are unsuitable for LINUX... they work great!
.............
Load LINUX on your Chromebook (there are lots of guides to this but all those which talk about crouton are out of date -its now dead easy).

open your terminal

type:

```
sudo apt update
```

(you may need to provide your password )

then wait a little bit

then type

```
sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

you can access QGIS by typing in the terminal /usr/bin/qgis

OK that didn give me the latest release, but the LTR is good enough to get started.